# Ninject WebAPI The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository, ninject

So I am using a simple repository pattern with Attributes and Filters as recommended [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/wiki/Conditional-bindings-for-filters) since I am using the `Ninject.Web.WebApi-RC` package from NuGet.

This works for the first request but since I have my `DbContext` in request scope, it is disposed on all subsequent requests.

Here is my attribute:

```
public class CommunicationKeyValidationAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
}
```

Here is my filter:

```
public class CommunicationKeyValidationFilter : AbstractActionFilter
{
    public CommunicationKeyValidationFilter(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
 }
```

Here is my repository:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Here are my Ninject bindings:

```
this.Kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
this.Kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().InRequestScope();
this.Kernel.BindHttpFilter<CommunicationKeyValidationFilter>(FilterScope.Action)
        .WhenActionMethodHas<CommunicationKeyValidationAttribute>()
        .InRequestScope();
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public class HomeController 
{
    [CommunicationKeyValidation]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

The issue here is that the constructor on `CommunicationKeyValidationFilter` is only being called on the first request.  Is there a way that I can cause ninject to construct this filter each time it attempts to resolve the filter?

Comment: I was able to repro your problem: so I would say this a bug in Ninject which is caused by a feature (bug?) in web.api. It seems Web.Api itself caches the filters: I found this in the [autofac web.api integration](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration): "Unlike the filter provider in MVC the one in Web API does not allow you to specify that the filter instances should not be cached. This means that all **filter attributes in Web API are effectively singleton instances that exist for the entire lifetime of the application.**"

Comment: Yeah, I believe I read the same article.  I was wondering if anyone had tackled this by writing a custom filter provider or something where it creates a new instance during each request.

Comment: Interestingly Ninject provides two filter providers `DefaultFilterProvider` and `NinjectFilterProvider` for Web.API...

Comment: But it seems it is not the fiterproviders fault. The cashing is done by Web.API in `ApiControllerActionSelector` which caches the `ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor`s which caches the Filters in the  `_filterPipeline`...

Comment: As a dirty workaround: don't use constructor injection in your `CommunicationKeyValidationFilter` but resolve your services in the `OnActionExecuting` method:  `public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            ((IRepository)
                actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IRepository))).Do();
        }`

Comment: Yeah, I already tried overriding the `DefaultFilterProvider`...  I thought about using a workaround like that but I was hoping there was a way to do this correctly but it looks like `ApiControllerActionSelector` is pretty locked down (if that's where the filters are cached). http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/277

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Filters are cached by the WebApi. They should be in transient scope so that it the WebApi can manage the lifecycle. Because of the long lifecycle you can't have any dependency that have a shorter lifecycle.

What you can do though is to create your repository during execution of the filter. For this it is best to inject a factory using the `NinjectFactoryExtension`:

```
public class CommunicationKeyValidationFilter : AbstractActionFilter
{
    public CommunicationKeyValidationFilter(IRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        this.repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var repository = this.repositoryFactory.CreateRepository();
    }
 }

 public interface IRepositoryFactory { IRepository CreateRepository(); }
 kernel.Bind<IRepositoryFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't as convenient as just using constructor injection but it solves my issue.

Comment: @Remo Is this caching of filters specific to WebApi?  Or should we use factories for MVC filters as well?  Thanks for all your work.

Comment: No it's not specific to WebAPI. Mvc does the same

Comment: This explains my random exceptions. perfect!